# Laravel Dingo API Route 404 for @show

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, dingo-api

Im using Dingo to build out an API and up until this point I've had no problems with the routes, until trying to add show into the controller, I'm just getting a 404.

Details here:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "404 Not Found",
        "status_code": 404,
        "debug": {
            "line": 179,
            "file": "/var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
            "trace": [
                "#0 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(546): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection->match(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
                "#1 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(525): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->findRoute(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
                "#2 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(511): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
                "#3 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Adapter/Laravel.php(81): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
                "#4 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php(513): Dingo\\Api\\Routing\\Adapter\\Laravel->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), 'v1')",
                "#5 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(126): Dingo\\Api\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
                "#6 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(114): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
                "#7 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
                "#8 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
                "#9 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
                "#10 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
                "#11 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(103): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
                "#12 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
                "#13 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
                "#14 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
                "#15 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
                "#16 /var/www/html/myapi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
                "#17 /var/www/html/myapi/api/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
                "#18 {main}"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a portion of my route file
**api.php**

```
$api->group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function(Router $api) {
    $api->get('protected', function() {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Access to protected resources granted! You are seeing this text as you provided the token correctly.'
        ]);
    });

    $api->get('refresh', [
        'middleware' => 'jwt.refresh',
        function() {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'By accessing this endpoint, you can refresh your access token at each request. Check out this response headers!'
            ]);
        }
    ]);

    $api->get('leads', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\LeadController@index');
    $api->get('leads/{$id}', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\LeadController@show');
    $api->post('leads/store', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\LeadController@store');
    $api->put('leads/update/{$id}', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\LeadController@update');
    $api->post('leads/update/{$id}', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\LeadController@update');
});
```

And the show function in the controller:
**LeadController.php**

```
public function show(Lead $leads, $id)
    {
        dd($id);

        $lead = Lead::with('user', 'source', 'industry', 'status')->find($id);

        //if(!$lead)
        //    return $this->response->error('invalid_data', 400);

        //return fractal($lead, new LeadTransformer())->respond();
    }
```

I've attempted to do a Die'n'Dump to ensure the ID is coming through, but it doesn't appear to be getting that far. Both the @index and @store work no problems and if I change LeadController@index to LeadController@show, the route works, and I of course get the error regarding the second parameter.

Really at a loss as to why this won't work, so help here would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, from looking too hard, and not enough sleep, the reason it didn't work was because the variable was set as ***{$id}*** not ***{id}*** as it should have been.

When using these variables, **don't** use the ***$*** sign!